# onSizeChanged() is Not Called or Called with Unexpected Parameters

Tags: android, layout, view

My application has the following architecture:

- Application subclass that has cached so-called scheme objects that hold actual layout data of the main view
- Main view that gets cached scheme from the Application in onSizeChanged() callback using (width, height) pair as a key

So, in brief it works as following: Application object generates scheme objects for all possible (width, height) pairs (for horizontal and vertical orientation) and stores them. The main view object gets scheme from the Application when onSizeChanged() is called and later uses that scheme to draw.

The problem I have sometimes scheme appears to be null. It particularly happens when I run another application then switch to mine one (happens extremely rarely, not always).

I have two possible explanations:

- (width, height) passed to onSizeChanged() sometimes slightly differ from the "old" values, so that proper scheme cant be found
- onSizeChanged() is just not called (say, the system re-creates my view and doesnt call onSizeChanged() somehow)

But I cant find any reason for both options... I found onSizeChanged() sometimes isn't called when using soft keyboard, but I dont use keyboard at all.

Please help!

Comment: What r u trying to draw exactly?

Comment: Just several rectangles ("artificial" buttons). I calculate their bounds beforehand and generate their bitmaps in the Application making them available for the later use in the Main view.

Comment: Which view you are trying to take height and width of?

Comment: Its a subclass of View, inserted via LinearLayout, no margins, fills parent in both directions.